# Missing edit-tags rollover

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I can't hover over the spot next to the tags for an "edit tags" button anymore:

[image]

This used to work before the graduation, but now I have to click on edit and I am too lazy for that.

Comment: I want to say, that I am sure that you will break 10k soon. You are doing a great job here.

Comment: @Heslacher Thanks! I'm hoping to someday earn that [rubber duck swag](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P1d7p.png).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Since the reputation threshold changed, "Inline editing" requires 10k rep.

You'll be there soon :p

Answer (score 5):

One of the downsides of losing privileges: you, well, lose privileges :)

If I remember correctly, you'll get it back at 10K - just keep doing what you're doing and, in 6-8 weeks it'll fix itself!

Comment: Damn. 11 seconds to my probably first accepted answer on meta. :p

Comment: @TopinFrassi I used the koala as the tie-breaker. Koalas are awesome.